# Insert in db with codeigniter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, insert

I want to insert in db with codeigniter. Done it in basic way but wanna use ajax. I'm using a theme with bootstrap also. Here is my code:

```
<input name="c_address" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="c_phone" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="c_mail" type="text" class="form-control">
<?php echo form_open('customer_add/add_new'); ?>
<button name="btn-send" id="btn-send" type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">save</button>
<?=form_close();?>
```

And my **script**:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $('#btn-send').on('click', function () {
          var value = {
              'c_user': $('#c_user').val(),
              'c_phone': $('#c_phone').val(),
              'c_mail': $('#c_mail').val(),
          };

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'customer_add/add_new',
              data: value,
              cache: false,
              success: function (result) {
                  console.log(result);
                  alert(result);
              }
          })
      });
  });
</script>
```

And my **add_new function**:

```
<?php
public function add_new(){
    if($this->session->userdata('login') == true){
        $config = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'c_address',
                'label' => '"آدرس"',
                'rules' => 'trim'
                ),
            array(
                'field' => 'c_phone',
                'label' => '"شماره تماس"',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
                ),
            array(
                'field' => 'c_mail',
                'label' => '"آدرس ایمیل"',
                'rules' => 'trim|valid_email',
                )
            );
        if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $this->load->model('customers_model');
            $add['is_add'] = $this->customers_model->add_customer();
            echo $add;
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('home/customer_add_view');
        }
    }
    else{
        redirect('auth');
    }
}
?>
```

It Works well if not ajax! I'm saying even if I write a script by calling button's id, it doesn't work. But if I write a function like

```
function notify(){
alert('note');
}
```

And put it in button's onclick="notify", It work. I don't know if there's something wrong with the id selector or the jquery code.

I can't even do simple alert by button's id. Is it because of bootstrap?

Edit:

@DFriend: This is my entire add_new function:

```
    public function add_new(){
        if($this->session->userdata('login') == true){
        $config = array(
        array(
                'field' => 'c_address',
                'label' => '"آدرس"',
                'rules' => 'trim'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'c_phone',
                'label' => '"شماره تماس"',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'c_mail',
                'label' => '"آدرس ایمیل"',
                'rules' => 'trim|valid_email',
                )
);
    if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
            {
                $this->load->model('customers_model');
                $add['is_add'] = $this->customers_model->add_customer();
                echo $add;
            }
            else{
                $this->load->view('home/customer_add_view');
            }
            }
        else{
            redirect('auth');
        }
```

It Works good in not ajax! I'm saying even if i write a script by calling button's id, it doesn't work. But if i write a function like

```
function notify(){
alert('note');
}
```

And put it in button's onclick="notify", It work. I dont know if theres something wrong with the id selector or the jquery code.

My script:

```
$('#btnbtn').on('click', function () { 
    alert('hi');
  )};
```

My button:

```
<div class="form-group">                                       
     <button id="btnbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">ذخیره</button>
        </div>
```

In inspect console error:

Empty string passed to getElementById().

Whats the problem?

Comment: Is that the entire `add_new` function? If not, please show the whole thing.

Comment: No, it's not because of bootstrap. How does `add_customer()` get input? Show that function too.

Comment: You should put your input elements ***INSIDE*** of your `<form></form>` container.

Comment: Change to this in the javascript. `$('#btn-send').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); ...` This will stop the normal form posting from happening.

Comment: Just edited my question.